# How to get image source value from json object

Tags: json

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function loadmemberg(m)
{
   $.ajax({
   type   : "POST",
   url    : "details.php",
   data   : {gvalue:m},
   success: function(data){
   var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
         $('#name').val(obj[0].FullName);
         $('#place').val(obj[0].PlaceName);
   var obj="";
         },
   error: function(data){
   alert("Please Enter a valid details");  
   }
   }); 
}
</script>
<html>
<div><input type="text" id="name"/></div>
<div><input type="text" id="place"/></div>
<div><img src="" id="image"></div>
</html>
```

This is my code and i want to get my image filename from the json object and display it in the html
How can i do it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON object must contain image filename that you want to display.
Then to set the src attribute value you should add this code to success function:

```
$("#image").attr("src", obj[0].ImageFileName);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you be more specific of how your code can help the original poster?

Comment: How to include the image path...? My images are stored in image folder

Comment: thanx a lot, it worked for me...$("#image").attr("src", "../../images/" + obj[0].PhotoFileName);

Comment: Hey i have one more question. Initially my <div style="display:none"><img src="" id="image"></div>. I want to change the style display to show/block when the name is entered. How can i do this in JSON....? I tried $("#image").show(); But it is not working